# Dynamically wrap named exports with extra middleware before exporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, composition

I have a few exported functions from ES6 module like:

```
export const funA = params => 'hello funA';
export const funB = params => 'hello funB';
```

I'd like to wrap them before exporting:

```
const wrapper = params => fun => {
  // some extra logic
  Object.assign(params, { extra: 'data' });
  return fun(params);
};

export const funA = wrapper(params => 'hello funA');
export const funB = wrapper(params => 'hello funB');
```

It works this way, but I'm wondering if it's possible to define `funA` and `funB` without `wrapper` invocation in a way simmilar to:

```
import { mapValues } from 'lodash';

const wrapper = params => fun => {
  // some extra logic
  Object.assign(params, { extra: 'data' });
  return fun(params);
};

const funA = params => 'hello funA';
const funB = params => 'hello funB';

export default mapValues({ funA, funB }, wrapper);
```

The issue with above snippet is that named exports are not used.

Can I achieve named exports with possibility to wrap them with `wrapper` middleware dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you going to determine which wrapper middleware?

You could do something like

```
export const funA = middleware => params => 'funA'
export const funB = middleware => params => 'funB'
```

then at the callsite:

```
import { funA } from './module.js'

const funFunA = middleware(funA)
```

But this is sounding more and more like a case for function composition:

```
import { funA } from './module.js'
import { nextFun } from './other.js'

const funFunA = compose(nextFun, funA)
```

Depending on your needs it might also be worth your while using something like the `Arrow` monad

https://evilsoft.github.io/crocks/docs/crocks/Arrow.html

Edit:

```
const _funA = a => b

export const funA = (...args) => {
  switch (currentMood) {
    case 'saucy': return sauce(_funA(...args))
    default: return _funA(...args)
}
```

Comment: Indeed - it's all about composition. I don't think that this `Arrow` may help. The problem is that I have to export already prepared named function (there is no access to the caller part).

Comment: so who gets to decide on the shape of the caller if you don't

Comment: then how do you determine which other functions to apply?

Comment: In `serverless.yml` it's possible to define the handler for specific function with `handler: src/index.funA`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid repeating `wrapper` in every line, you could use destructuring assignment and named export. However, this requires repeating `{ funA, funB, ..., funXYZ }`.

```
import { mapValues } from 'lodash';

const wrapper = params => fun => {
    // some extra logic
    Object.assign(params, { extra: 'data' });
    return fun(params);
};

let funA = params => 'hello funA';
let funB = params => 'hello funB';

let { funA, funB } = mapValues({ funA, funB }, wrapper);

export { funA, funB };
```